# How to connect to the database

Tags: oracle

I did not find this question on StackOverFlow.
I made a database with name DBATEAM.

When I shut down the terminal ORACLE_SID is left on the old base ORCL12C.
and when i connect to the `sqlplus / as sysdba` I connect to the base ORCL12C

How do I connect to DBATEAM database?

I'm a beginner in the Oracle, Thanks in advance

tnsnames.ora:

```
ORCL12C =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = ORCL12C)
    )
  )

LISTENER_ORCL12C =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))


ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 0.0.0.0)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)  
    ) 
  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you create that "database"? Is it, by any chance, a **schema** instead?

If it is a database, then you'll have to tell Oracle to connect to it by specifying its name as a part of the connect string, e.g.

```
sqlplus sys/its_password@dbateam as sysdba
                        --------
                        this
```

If it is a schema, then you'd

```
sqlplus dbateam/its_password@orcl12c
```

where `@orcl12` is optional (if there's no other database available).

Comment: It's a database.
I get error ERROR:
ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the specified identifier specified

Comment: Have a look at the TNSNAMES.ORA file - database's entry should be in there. If there are multiple TNSNAMES.ORA files on your computer, consider using only one in a directory whose location is stored in the TNSADMIN environment variable. Doing so, any Oracle product you have will use the same TNSNAMES.ORA file.

Comment: In tnsnames.ora I only have data associated with database orcl12c

Comment: So add DBATEAM in there.

Comment: I tried, but it seems I do not do it well,
I'll insert tnsnames into question

Comment: I'm glad you made it work; thank you for letting us know.